# ant taskdef class cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin that will run an Ant XML file programatically.
I used `org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelperImpl` and `org.apache.tools.ant.Project` then parse the Ant XML file and run a specific target, in this case `test`.

My Ant XML file looks like this:

```
<!-- project class path -->
<path id="projectClassPath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/jars">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- task definitions -->
<taskdef file="${basedir}/tasks.properties">
    <classpath refid="projectClassPath" />
</taskdef>

<!-- test custom ant task -->
<target name="test" description="test target">
    <customTask />
</target>

<!-- test echo -->
<target name="testEcho" description="test echo target">
    <echo message="this is a test."/>
</target>
```

The tasks.properties file looks like this:

```
customTask=my.custom.task.CustomTask
```

My java code that runs the Ant file programatically:

```
Project ant = new Project();
ProjectHelperImpl helper = new ProjectHelperImpl();
MyDefaultLogger log = new MyDefaultLogger();

ant.init();
helper.parse(ant, antXml);

log.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
ant.addBuildListener(log);
ant.executeTarget(testTarget);
```

Running the target `test` manually, is **fine**, but running the `test` target programatically displays this **error**:

```
taskdef class my.custom.task.CustomTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

If I will also be executing the file programatically without the `project class path`, `task definitions` and `test custom ant task` it will run successfully.

My assumption is that, when running the Ant file programatically, it did not register the classpath somehow?

**EDIT:** 
multiple target name `test` changed `<!-- test echo -->` target name to `testEcho`. (credits to: @smooth reggae)

Comment: Is there a typo in your sample? You have two targets called `test`

Comment: @smoothreggae: my bad, I have edited the target names now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix my error, I changed my Java implementation of calling the Ant XML file, and it worked like a charm.

My Java code looks like this:

```
// get the default custom classpath from the preferences
AntCorePreferences corePreferences = AntCorePlugin.getPlugin().getPreferences();
URL[] urls = corePreferences.getURLs();

// get the location of the plugin jar
File bundleFile = FileLocator.getBundleFile(myPlugin.getBundle());
URL url = bundleFile.toURI().toURL();

// bond urls to complete classpath
List<URL> classpath = new ArrayList<URL>();
classpath.addAll(Arrays.asList(urls));
classpath.add(url);

AntRunner runner = new AntRunner();
// set custom classpath
runner.setCustomClasspath(classpath.toArray(new URL[classpath.size()]));
// set build file location
runner.setBuildFileLocation(xmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
// set build logger
runner.addBuildLogger(MyDefaultLogger.class.getName());
// set the specific target to be executed
runner.setExecutionTargets(new String[] { "test" });
// run
runner.run();
```